# how to put all inputs from a use into a csv file

Tags: csv

please I need help just two weeks in python

Scenario
You are creating an application that will feed into a Tourism business database for location of
interesting sites in the country (Ghana.)
Your application is a simple command line interface that will query the users on mobile phone using
USSD.
The application will ask the user for the following:

1. Name
2. Region
3. Category
4. Name of interesting find
5. What makes it special
   The application framework will be handled by senior developers.
   Task to do
   Your task is to create a simple python command line application that will ask the user for the name,
   region, category, name of point of interest and point of interest comment. The following are
   requirements:
   a. The region must be a valid region in the country
   b. The category must be taken from this list: [Music, Dance, Art, Food, Industry, History, Nature,
   Other]
   c. The details should be saved to a single text file. New entries should be appended to the file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a "we'll do your work for you for free" site.
Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with and example output that you expect.

Comment: The reason you dont see my effort is because i had code formatting challenges.i tried resolving it but couldnt

Comment: You still need to show your effort, and not just put a task, which we need to write out for you, without any examples. See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net)